# C++: Return NULL instead of struct

Tags: c++, error-handling, null-object-pattern

I have a struct `Foo`. In pseudocode:

```
def FindFoo:
   foo = results of search
   foundFoo = true if a valid foo has been found  

   return foo if foundFoo else someErrorCode
```

How can I accomplish this in C++?

**Edited** to remove numerous inaccuracies.

Comment: Your return type is inconsistent. If the search succeeds, it is `Foo&`; if it fails, it is `ErrorCode`. A solution to this problem would be to return a `Foo*`, which points to the element that was found, or is NULL if no element was found.

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate: [Nullable values in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2537942)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

C++ objects can never be null or empty. Pointers can hold a null pointer value indicating they point at nothing.

The typical solution would be to throw an exception. Otherwise, use a pointer; just make sure you aren't returning the address of a temporary.

I wouldn't recommend trying to teach yourself C++ with knowledge from other languages, you'll hurt yourself. Grab a [good beginner-level book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), it's the best way to learn.

Comment: I think the typical solution would be to mimik the STL which returns an iterator like object that point to invalid objects (one past the end of the container).

Comment: @Martin: I'll just say that's a more generalized pointer and meet you half-way. :P

Comment: Returning an iterator-like object only makes sense if you're creating a container that you want to be able to iterate over. Where a `find` function is involved, that's potentially the case, but not necessarily.

Comment: I think doing C++ by applying knowledge from other languages is excellent; it will improve C++ to become more modern in the end.

Answer (score 3):

Throw an exception. That's what they're for.

Answer (score 3):

You can look into `boost::optional` and see if it fits your needs. However:

> return foo if foundFoo **else someErrorCode**

This makes me think that you might be better off throwing an exception if you don't find foo.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is to return a pointer to a foo:

```
public Foo* findFoo()
{
    return fooFound ? new fooResult() : NULL;
}
```

Another possibility to define a `NullFoo` of some kind, possibly as a `struct` extending `Foo` with an empty implementation.  For more information about the latter idea, you can read about the [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Edit: The modified question is somewhat different, and as other people have mentioned, you may be best off throwing an exception rather than doing either of the above.

Comment: fooFound is just the condition to check, fooResult is what's returned.

Comment: Another possibility is `boost::optional<Foo>`. Then you don't have to remember to delete it.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: Thanks - nabbing that to complete my answer #3

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't work in C# either.  You should return a pointer to Foo.

Comment: @Dura, the question is "How can I accomplish this in C++?"

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in C++ without resorting to pointers or a library solution outside the standard library. (Boost is not a part of the standard library, it's a 3rd party solution.)

In C#, you can use a `Nullable<Foo>`.

Contrary to Billy's comment, structs are value types, not reference types, and Nullable can be applied to ***any*** value type, not just built-ins. The following compiles just fine:

```
struct Test {
    int Blah;
}
void Main() {
    System.Nullable<Test> proof;
}
```

Comment: No, you can't. First of all, Nullable is only valid on the internal types, not on user defined types like `Foo`. Second, even if it were valid, it'd not help you anyway because object references can already be null. And finally, the OP asked to return an error code, not NULL.

Comment: @Billy: Easy on the -1s. struct means value type, not reference and you can do a nullable value type - that's the whole point

Comment: +1 factually correct re the .NET bit. Ditto the C++ bit, though omits ways around dropping to pointers [such as Null Object pattern, throwing, wrapping in a boost::optional]. +1ing as answer not off topic or incorrect. Far more irellevant and incomplete answers have been upvoted here.

Answer (score 0):

Is not finding a foo really an exceptional situation? Then throw an exception.  Expect to not find foo? have the function return an error code and pass the foo out via a reference parameter, where foo is only valid if the function returns no error.

Comment: That would be my approach. Keeping things simple, and dependencies minimal.

Answer (score -1):

You cant do this in C# either - you would need to return `new Foo()`, not `null` to make the compiler happy.

Ditto the C++ case - you need to instantiate a struct if you're going to return by value. If not, you want to return by pointer (in which case you'd be `new`ing or returning a pointer to one allocated in another manner, which brings messy ownership transfer semantics into the equation).

EDIT: Based on your update. It seems you want to return either a value or a 'null' meta-value that indicates 'not found'. You can do this in a number of ways:

1. `throw` if it fails, otherwise unconditionally return a value
2. return a pointer - but this leaves the responsibility for `delet`ing it up in the air if it's not something that's going to stay in memory long term
3. wrap it in a [templated] wrapper object that handles the conditionality in the same way that .NET's `Nullable<T>` would (I'll let someone chime in with the right one UPDATE: @Mike Seymour says it's `boost::optional<foo>`)
4. use the Null Object pattern to return an appropriate value which does the right thing when treated as a valid resut on the client side