# Best way to represent Nullable member in C++?

Tags: c++, nullable, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nullable values in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537942/nullable-values-in-c)

What is the best way to represent nullable member in C++?

In C#, we can use `Nullable<T>` type. Such a data type is very much needed as not everything can have *meaningful* value. It is so important data type that [@Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) has spent one entire chapter, spanned over 27 pages, describing only `Nullable<T>` in his outstanding book [*C# in Depth*](http://csharpindepth.com/).

One simple example can be a `Person` class<sup>1</sup>, defined as:

```
struct Person
{
  std::string Name;
  DateTime    Birth;
  DateTime    Death;
  //...
};
```

As a person always have birthdate, so the `Birth` member of the above class will always have some *meaningful* value. But how about `Death`?  What should it value be if the person is alive? In C#, this member can be declared as `Nullable<DataTime>`<sup>2</sup> which can be assigned with `null` if the person is alive.

In C++, what is the best way to solve this? As of now, I've only one solution in mind: declare the member as *pointer*:

```
 DataTime *Death;
```

Now its value can be `nullptr` when the person is alive. But it forces the use of `new` for dead person, as it's going to have some valid value. It in turn implies one cannot rely on the *default* copy-semantic code generated by the compiler. The programmer has to write copy-constructor, copy-assignment, destructor following [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) (C++03), Or in C++11, [rule of five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c0x).

So do we have any better, elegant solution to this problem than just making it *pointer*?

---

<sup>1. Other examples include relational database tables, as in many DBMSs columns can be nullable.</sup>

<sup>2. There is also a shorthand for this. One can write `DataTime?` which is *exactly* same as `Nullable<DateTime>`.</sup>

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: I think, you should close other topic, as this topic has *more* and better answers. :D.. and I believe, I've described the problem in detail, at conceptual level.

Comment: You can't just trundle around Stack Overflow posting duplicates and trying to get the originals closed because you prefer your own.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: the moderators may decide to merge the two questions though. It may be necessary to vie for their attention.

Comment: @Nawaz: if you can improve a question (for example by adding a detailed conceptual level) then you're free to edit it.

Comment: @SteveJessop: You're implying that I knew that possible duplicate. I say, I didn't know that.

Comment: @Nawaz: Sorry, I meant that since you know now, you could do that edit, instead of arguing for the other question to be closed. I can't remember exactly what happens when questions are merged -- you might be wise to take a copy of your question *now*, because if a mod does merge it may be that your question text will vanish, losing any improvements that could be applied to the other question.

Comment: @Steve: ...which is a bit of an unfortunate site flaw, in my view.

Comment: If boost is not an option, take a look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28811646/213871) that resembles .NET nullables.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could look into [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html):

```
struct Person
{
  std::string               Name;
  DateTime                  Birth;
  boost::optional<DateTime> Death;
  //...
};
```

- Your `Death` is "uninitialised" at first.
- You can then assign a value to it with `=`, like `Death = myDateTime`.
- When `Death.is_initialized()`, you can use `Death.get()`.
- Uninitialise it again with `Death.reset()`.

For simple cases like this, though, it's usually considered more coherent to just pick your own blatant sentinel value like, say, a `DateTime` of "0000-00-00 00:00:00".

Comment: Please expand on this, as to how should it be used? What would be value of `Boost.Optional` for dead persons?

Comment: How did you edit this question and not make the "edited" link show up?

Comment: @RedX: I didn't edit the answer! It was always great! ;)

Comment: No way, first time i entered this topic your answer just said: "boost.optional".

Comment: @RedX: You must be losing your mind!

Comment: (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted)

Comment: I believe you should be able to test `Death` as it is (i.e. no need for `is_initialized()` - AFAIK, it supports safe bool), and `operator*` to get reference (this is purely syntactic sugar though...)

Comment: @Nim: [safe bool is equiv to `.get() != 0` here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/detailed_semantics.html) but `.get()` returns the encapsulated object (or various refs thereof). So it's actually a wrapper around safe-booling the encapsulated object.

Comment: `reset` and `is_initialized` are deprecated. You can uninitialize by assigning `boost::none` to it, and test for initialization with conversion to bool.

Comment: @RMartinho: Is the documentation wrong then? Should it say that conversion to bool is in fact `.get_ptr() != 0`?

Comment: @ildjarn: conversion-to-bool is deprecated? News to me.

Comment: No, `reset` and `is_initialized` are deprecated, and conversion to bool is recommended, just as @R.MartinhoFernandes said.

Comment: @ildjarn: Please read my comment, and the documentation, again. Conversion to bool is defined by the documentation to be equivalent to `.get() != 0`, not `.get_ptr() != 0`. And the former asserts when the object is not initialised. If the documentation is correct then quite clearly we are not supposed to determine whether our object is initialised via conversion to bool, unless immediate termination of our program is acceptable handling for an answer of "no".

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal `reset` and `is_initialized` are documented as deprecated. See for yourself: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/synopsis.html. I provided the alternatives: `x = boost::none` instead of `x.reset()` and `if(x)` instead of `if(x.is_initialized())`.

Comment: @RMartinho: Why is everybody obsessing over those two functions? I'm talking about the conversion to bool. Read my comments again please. You _cannot_ "test for initialization with conversion to bool" unless either: (a) the documentation is wrong about what conversion to bool does; (b) you don't mind `BOOST_ASSERT`ions as flow control.

Comment: @Tomalak : Everyone is "obsessing" over those two functions because your answer says to use them and they're deprecated. Regarding the safe-bool operator, the documentation is **obviously** wrong, as `get() != 0` is **obviously** nonsensical. A cursory glance at the source code also reveals the safe-bool operator to be safe to use when the object is uninitialized.

Comment: If boost is not an option, take a look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28811646/213871) that resembles .NET `Nullable<T>`.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on `DateTime` - like @Tomalak says in his answer, `boost::optional<>` is a generic solution. However if for example your `DateTime` is a `boost::posix_time::ptime`, then there is already support for *special values* (for example `not_a_date_time` or `pos_infin`) - you could use these.

Answer (score 5):

Every project I've worked on has had some sort of `Fallible`, `Maybe` or
`Nullable` template class.  (The actual name tends to reflect what the
application first needed it for: `Fallible` as a return value,
`Nullable` to model databases, etc.).  More recently, Boost has
introduced `boost::optional`; regretfully, they use implicit conversions
instead of an `isValid` (named) function, which results in noticeably
less readable code (to the point where I'd avoid it, except maybe to 
implement my own `Maybe`).

Comment: If you don't like the boolean conversion, why not just add a free function template: `template <typename T> bool isValid(const boost::optional<T> &o) { return o; }`? Seems easier than wrapping the whole class.

Comment: @SteveJessop Well, you also want to get rid of the pointer operations; it's **not** a smart pointer, so it shouldn't look like one.  In many ways, `boost::optional` seems to have suffered from feature creep.  (Of course, the same can be said of my `Fallible`---or probably any other class that's been around a long time and has been used in a variety of applications.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do what legions of programmers did before you! Use a specific value as "not present"... For example I've heard that "1 Jan 2000" was pretty common :-) :-) For interoperability reasons you could use "19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC" :-) :-) (it's a joke, if it isn't clear. I'm referencing the Y2K problem and the Y2038 problem. I'm showing the problem of using "special" dates as states... Things like 11-11-11 and similar)

The maximum/minimum value of your `DataTime` is probably more correct :-) And it's still wrong, because you are mixing a "state" with a "value". Better that you rebuild the `Nullable` type in C++ (in the end it's quite easy: a templated class with a bool for null/not null and the T field)

Comment: The minimum value would be even more obvious.

Comment: @MSalters: The problem comes when some entity really died at the minimum date.

Answer (score 1):

as death is particularly unlikely to be any time *before* birth you could just as well set it to birth - 1 initially and have it changed on the actual event. in more common terms you'd probably call birth - 1 a sentinel value or placeholder value. you could also pick a constant value low enough not to be mistaken for a real value, but that assumes you have some knowledge of your data.

Comment: But this invites client code to make compilable and sometimes correct looking errors like `age = death - birth;`.

Answer (score -1):

I would create a static member which represent null value, than compare the address of date of death to the address of the static object. If they are equal the value is NULL.