# Implementation of the std::optional class

Tags: c++

I need to implement a quick solution for optional values. I don't want to drag in any third party libraries.

How are the optional classes implemented in general? Does an optional object still default-construct the underlying object when it's in the 'null-state'?

Comment: Have you looked into the [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) implementation?

Comment: The C++ standard library isn't a third party library. I suppose you do not wish to start using C++14 yet?

Comment: @E_net4 My compiler does not support it yet.

Comment: cut/paste boost::optional

Comment: Basically speaking, Boost.Optional (as suggested by Angew) is what was eventually accepted as std::optional. So if you're burdened with an old(er) compiler, Boost.Optional is the way to go. (Similar with e.g. Boost.smart_ptr and std::shared_ptr.) I understand the reluctance regarding third-party libraries, but C++ without Boost is bound to reinvent much-proven wheels.

Comment: Look at [this thread and the related comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875045/implementing-boostoptional-in-c11) for a quick-and-dirty implementation (-- if you definitely have no way to include the std or boost optional class)

Answer (score 14):

> How are the optional classes implemented in general?

Typically, a boolean flag to indicate whether or not it's empty, and a suitably sized and aligned byte array to store the value.

> Does an optional object still default-construct the underlying object when it's in the 'null-state'?

No; that would impose an unnecessary requirement on the stored type, as well as causing potential unwanted side-effects. The stored object would be created with placement-new when the `optional` becomes non-empty, and destroyed with a destructor call when it becomes empty.

For a quick-and-dirty implementation, if you don't need all the flexibility of the Boost or proposed standard versions, you could simply store a default-constructed object.

> I don't want to drag in any third party libraries.

I would reconsider why you don't feel you want that. The Boost implementation is header-only, well tested, and should be directly replaceable by the standard version if and when that arrives. I'd certainly trust it more than something I cobbled together myself.

Answer (score 3):

First of all I highly recommend you to take a look at Boost (specifically at Boost.Optional) - it is almost standard practice to use Boost and it would save you reinventing the wheel.

If for some reason you are reluctant to use Boost.Optional, there are a bunch of similar header-only libraries, for example https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional

Answer (score 2):

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) or earlier you can use a null-checked `T*` or just a `std::pair<T, bool>`. The problem with the latter is if your default construction of `T` is expensive, that may be wasteful.

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) or later you can still use `T*` but you can also use [`std::optional<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). Here the latter only constructs a `T` if it is valid.

It's noteworthy that the `std::optional` is a good option in only a few cases: https://topanswers.xyz/cplusplus?q=923#a1085

Comment: I disagree that `std::optional<T>` is a good option in only a few cases. The point of using `std::optional<T>` instead of `T*` is that `std::optional<T>` contains a `T` directly so that you don't need an extra layer of indirection to represent an owned maybe non-existent value.

Comment: I agree with cuddlebugCuller. What's more, the interface is much clearer than a rare pointer that does not say anything about whether it could be nullptr

Comment: "null-checked `T*`" - specifically, you could use `std::unique_ptr<T>`

Answer (score 1):

[std::optional from Scratch](http://www.club.cc.cmu.edu/%7Eajo/disseminate/2017-02-15-Optional-From-Scratch.pdf) introduces how to implement a optional class

Answer (score -1):

Here is a start to mimicking [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). Not the trickiest implementation and has a lot more that should be added.

```
template <typename T>
struct optional {
private:
    bool _has_value;
    T _value;
public:
    optional() : _has_value{false}, _value{} {}
    optional(T v) : _has_value{true}, _value{v} {}
    bool has_value() const {return _has_value;}
    T value() const {
        if (_has_value) return _value;
        throw std::bad_optional_access();
    }
    T value_or(T def) const {
        return _has_value ? _value : def;
    }
    optional<T>& operator=(T v) {
        _has_value = true;
        _value = v;
        return *this;
    }
    void reset() {_has_value = false;}
};
```

Comment: This initializes a `T` instance even when it doesn't contain a value.

Comment: How would you avoid that?

Comment: One possibility is to use a union of T and a char array

Comment: Can't declare a std datatype (e.g. std::vector) in a union.

Comment: See the second example in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union, which contains a union for a `std::string` and `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: This is non-transparent to the user who is forced to use placement new and invoke specific destructors. This is not a tenable solution.