# Checking if object exists when returning from a function with for loop

Tags: c++, oop, for-loop, error-handling

I am looking to find the correct way to use this kind of code safely:

```
renderer->renderEntity(entityManager->getEntity("player"));

Entity EntityManager::getEntity(string entityName) 
{
    for (int index = 0; index < entityVector.size(); ++index)
    {
        if (entityVector[index].getName() == entityName)
        {
            return entityVector[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Where you want to get an object from a container within an instance of a class, and want to check it exists, so you aren't making a call on an object that doesn't exist.

I know I could alter the call to:

```
if (entityManager->getEntity("player" != nullptr)
{
    renderer->renderEntity("player");
}
```

I would like to avoid the double call to check the object exists. I guess this may be more a design than a syntax problem. Could I build the error checking into the getEntity() function that contains the for loop? I am not sure since the return value is Entity, so an Entity object must be returned. (same if it is a pointer, this isn't the code in my project, just a similar example).

Comment: How common is it that an entity of that name won't exist? You could throw an exception if this is a rare occurrence. Another option would be to take the standard library approach and return an iterator to the element, or to `entityVector.end()` if it doesn't exist.

Comment: What should your method return if the entity is not present?

Comment: I would suggest using a `std::map`

Comment: You can create a default object that gets returned if the item doesn't exist; that object could have some benign behavior, or it could have a method that tells you it's not real, or it could throw an exception for every method.

Comment: You could change `renderEntity` to `renderEntityIfExists` and return if a bad entity is passed in

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537942/nullable-values-in-c

Comment: Another option would be `std::optional`.

Comment: Lots of useful information here, thanks all! The ideal solution for my situation is from @Kenman Tsang with the Null Object pattern. TartanLlama - I am storing a lot of data in vectors and maps in my game engine: entities, textures, models, tilemaps and so on. It's a personal project so unlikely the error will occur, but I am just looking to get cleaner and safer code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help. A simple null object pattern

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern

```
class Entity
{
public:
    virtual void render()
    {
        // do somthing
    }
};

class EmptyEntity final : public Entity 
{
public:
    void render() override
    {
        //Do nothing or print log
    }
} static g_EmptyEntity;

Entity EntityManager::getEntity(string entityName) 
{
    for (int index = 0; index < entityVector.size(); ++index)
    {
        if (entityVector[index].getName() == entityName)
        {
            return entityVector[index];
        }
    }
    return g_EmptyEntity;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I am wanting, overriding any functions didn't occur to me. Really nice solution, I thought there would be a design pattern for it! Thank you.

Comment: As you return by value, you got object slicing.

Comment: Yes Jarod42. But as the asker dont have any more detail, so I cant include all the details.   Entity& EntityManager::getEntity(string entityName) can help

Comment: Return by reference is correct, else `EmptyEntity::render()` is never called with `EntityManager::getEntity("NotFound").render()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the return type: make getEntity() return a pointer, and NULL if the object is not present.

Alternatively as @ TartanLlama suggested you could return an iterator.

Other option (good only in some cases): your method could remember the `entityName` of the last time it has been invoked and the resulting index. When entering you first check if the current input is equal to the previous input: in that case you return the stored index without searching again.

Comment: That would work, but I was hoping to be able to not have to check if the object is NULL before using it, so I don't have a lot of if statements clogging the code up.

Your second point is a good one. I like that, skipping the search if you are looking for an object you found very recently. Definitely something I could use for efficiency, thanks!

Comment: Checking if a object is NULL is the same as checking if the element is present, they are the same case. I don't see how it can help unless this method findEntityByName() generate the element if it does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

Returning pointer would be the simpler/clearer:

```
Entity* EntityManager::findEntityByName(const std::string& entityName) 
{
    const auto it = std::find_if(entityVector.begin(), entityVector.end(),
                                 [&](const auto& e) {
                                      return e.getName() == entityName;
                                 } );
    if (it == entityVector.end()) { // Not found.
        return nullptr;
    }
    return std::addressof(*it);
}
```

And then

```
auto* entity = entityManager->findEntityByName("player");
if (entity  != nullptr)
{
    renderer->renderEntity(entity);
}
```

Comment: What I was hoping to get is the case where I don't need to check if the object is null before I make a call using it. But there's some really nice stuff in your answer, I didn't know about std::find_if() and std::addressof(). Thanks, they will be useful in the future for me!