# Inability to overload Dot '.' operator in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have hard time understanding the explanation from Stroustrup for what difficulties one must have faced, if operator overloading for '.' was allowed.

See this quote from Bjarne Stroustrup:

> Operator . (dot) could in principle be overloaded using the same technique as used for ->. However, doing so can lead to questions about whether an operation is meant for the object overloading . or an object referred to by . For example:

```
class Y {
public:
    void f();
    // ...
};

class X {    // assume that you can overload .
    Y* p;
    Y& operator.() { return *p; }
    void f();
    // ...
};

void g(X& x)
{
    x.f();    // X::f or Y::f or error?
}
```

In the above example why should there be any confusion while executing `x.f()`  ?

```
Y& operator.() { return *p; }
```

Here is what i think:

1. operator.() is called on x hence isn't it obvious and intuitive that `Y& operator.()( return *p; }` should be called ?
2. Upon returning `*p` which points to object of type Y and hence `Y::f()` should be called finally ( not `X::f()` )

What am i missing in Stroustup's explanation? Why is it not straightforward?

Comment: "hence `Y::f()` should be called finally" But isn't that confusing to someone reading that code? Normally `x.f()` would call the `f` member of `x`, but in this case that doesn't happen.

Comment: @ScottHunter Well, if the example is from Stroustrup and supposed to illustrate confusion, should not it be confusing :)?

Comment: This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520035/why-cant-you-overload-the-operator-in-c) talks about the same problem.

Comment: @AlexD : Exactly my point. Overloading is meant to be confusing. But if stroustup is saying its not straightfoward then it has to be something. Hence this question

Comment: @AlexD: No you can't. If `x` has a function named `f()`, you wouldn't be able to call that function with the syntax `x->f()`.

Comment: @Raw N  i am referring to the same question and the example from the accpeted answer, which is unclear to me

Comment: @AlexD with the `.` operator overloaded though you would need to provide some way of actually calling `X::f`. That isn't an issue with `->`.

Comment: @anurag86: I don't think it is MEANT to be confusing; its not like confusion is a goal.

Comment: @GregKikola In case of overloaded `.`, you could call `f` true non-overloaded `->`.

Comment: @AlexD Then every access would need to be through a pointer. I mean, it'd work, but seems kind of strange.

Comment: @AlexD: Yes, `(&x)->f()` works. It's not clear to me what your point is though. How could that be confusing? Where is there any room for ambiguity? `operator.` can be ambiguous because `x` can have a member named `f`, and whatever is returned from `operator.` can also have a member named `f`.

Comment: Can someone please post a conclusive answer so that i can accept it

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes, you are right. Removing some possibly confusing comments...

Answer (score 49):

There has been some progress: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4477.pdf . Due to some technical problems this won't be in C++17, but I hope to see it for C++20.

Comment: It's profiles like these that make me wish SO had a "verified" indicator on the profile page :)

Comment: Any update on this? I'm having trouble tracking the status.

Comment: do we have the dot overload in c++2a yet?

Comment: Here's a later version of the proposal: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0416r1.pdf

Comment: Here's a competing proposal for solving many of the same problems, which tries to use a special form of inheritance-like delegation instead of overloading the dot operator: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0352r1.pdf