# Pointer wrapper with reference-like behaviour

Tags: c++

I have a templated API function that takes a container of objects:

```cpp
template <class Container> void fn(Container *container);
```

It uses some basic methods of `std` containers and expects to find objects that implement some methods.

I have a set/vector/map of pointers to these objects and I need to call this API.

Does anyone see any way of doing this through standard C++ classes? Short of creating a new class that contains a pointer to the original object and reimplements all of its methods through this pointer?

Some kind of generic wrapper that takes a pointer and implements reference-like behavior?

Related questions (if the answer to those was yes, they would have been possible solutions, but it is not the case):

[Inability to overload Dot '.' operator in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42183631/inability-to-overload-dot-operator-in-c)

[Why can't I make a vector of references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references)

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. Without knowing what `fn` does, and without an example of usage, I don't think you'll get an answer. [Here is a demo of a function taking a vector, a set, and a map](https://godbolt.org/z/a8od1qssh). No need for any wrapper.

Comment: The function takes a container of objects, I have pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the values stored in the container implement the member functions, wrap the container to iterate over the actual values instead of pointers.

Say you have `std::vector<T*> vec;`. You can create a view that iterates over the values after indirecting:

```cpp
auto reference_view = vec | std::views::transform([](auto* obj) -> auto& { return *obj; });
fn(&reference_view);
```

(And for a map, it might look like `std::views::transform([](const std::pair<auto, auto* const>& pair) -> auto& { return *(pair.second); })`).

Comment: Alas, it is C++20, but it is a very elegant solution